# How to remove outliers from a subset in R?

Tags: r, subset, outliers

I am very new to R and am trying to remove outliers from a subset to improve a GLM. The code I am using is:

```
data$sel <- ifelse(data$chol==8.3 & data$whr==1.14 ,(0), (1))
data
dim(data)
data2 <- subset(data, !(chol==8.3 & whr==1.14))
dim(data2)
```

I did this, however, when I tried to plot the graph with the new data, the point still shows up.  The code I used to plot the new graph is:

```
dataF2 <- subset(data2, sex=="F")
dataF2
dataM2 <- subset(data2, sex=="M")
dataM2

plot(chol ~ whr, data=data2, type="n", ylab="Cholesterol (mM/L)", xlab="Waist-hip Ratio") 

#### add each group of points:
points(dataF2$chol ~ dataF2$whr, pch=1, col="red")
points(dataM2$chol ~ dataM2$whr, pch=2, col="blue")

Females2 <- lm(chol ~ whr, data=dataF2)
summary(Females)
abline(-8.053, 14.801, col="red")
Males2 <- lm(chol ~ whr, data=dataM2)
summary(Males2)
abline(-3.5896, 8.5617, col="blue")
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or if I am missing some important steps. All I am trying to do is remove an outlier or two so that I can improve the GLM and then produce a graph without the outliers.

Data

```
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ age  : int  42 41 40 43 61 44 39 70 47 55 ...
 $ sex  : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ bmi  : num  28.5 26.2 25.2 29.3 34.6 26.7 25.5 33.2 28.8 31.4 ...
 $ whr  : num  0.83 0.82 0.84 0.82 0.89 0.81 0.93 0.97 0.86 0.88 ...
 $ sysbp: int  132 135 141 142 167 145 137 182 150 160 ...
 $ chol : num  4.2 3.3 4.3 4.1 5.5 4.4 3.9 6.7 4.7 5.2 ...
 $ smoke: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
```

data2:

```
'data.frame':   99 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ age  : int  42 41 40 43 61 44 39 70 47 55 ...
 $ sex  : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ bmi  : num  28.5 26.2 25.2 29.3 34.6 26.7 25.5 33.2 28.8 31.4 ...
 $ whr  : num  0.83 0.82 0.84 0.82 0.89 0.81 0.93 0.97 0.86 0.88 ...
 $ sysbp: int  132 135 141 142 167 145 137 182 150 160 ...
 $ chol : num  4.2 3.3 4.3 4.1 5.5 4.4 3.9 6.7 4.7 5.2 ...
 $ smoke: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ sel  : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Your code is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). please provide your data or some minimal form of it.

Comment: Your code is still not reproducible. Did Cedric's answer help?

Answer (score 0):

To subset your data, you can pass a vector of TRUE FALSE to lines.

Your dataframe is data2[line,columns]

```
data2 <- data2[data2$chol!=8.3 & data2$whr!=1.14,]
```

read [this r blogger example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/working-with-data-frames/) to better understand how to remove some lines from your data frame.

You could also have just used

```
data2 <- subset(data, (chol!=8.3 & whr!=1.14))
```

or

```
data2 <- subset(data, !(chol==8.3 | whr==1.14))
```

My guess is that you have no lines where both chol and whr have those values, 
you want to remove two different lines.

Final advice, check what you are passing, using the first formulation allows you to check that bit of code,

```
data2$chol!=8.3 & data2$whr!=1.14
```

And check if that returns the vector of TRUE FALSE you expect